# Getting values from a column in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I had intended to do this using the code in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614518/iterating-over-a-range-of-rows-using-ws-iter-rows-in-the-optimised-reader-of-ope), in the last block of code. However i get an error in the line `for cell in ws.iter_rows(range_string=range_expr):` saying that "Worksheet object has no attribute iter_rows". Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: did you check to see that you had the most updated version of openpyxl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

all i needed was to change the workbook declaration to the following: `wb = load_workbook('path/doc.xls', use_iterators=True)`, adding in the use_iterators paramater. Simple issue, simple solution :)