# How we can use iter_rows() in Python openpyxl package?

Tags: python, excel, canopy, openpyxl

I'm using `openpyxl` package in `Python(Canopy)` to use excel files. We have this tutorial in this link : [LINK](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file)

```
you can also use the openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows() method:

>>> tuple(ws.iter_rows('A1:C2'))
((<Cell Sheet1.A1>, <Cell Sheet1.B1>, <Cell Sheet1.C1>),
 (<Cell Sheet1.A2>, <Cell Sheet1.B2>, <Cell Sheet1.C2>))

>>> for row in ws.iter_rows('A1:C2'):
...        for cell in row:
...            print cell
<Cell Sheet1.A1>
<Cell Sheet1.B1>
<Cell Sheet1.C1>
<Cell Sheet1.A2>
<Cell Sheet1.B2>
<Cell Sheet1.C2>
```

How we can import `openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows()` method in python? I used this code:

```
import openpyxl as op
ms = op.load_workbook('mtest.xlsx')

ws = ms.active

op.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows()
```

This code returns:

```
type object 'Worksheet' has no attribute 'iter_rows'
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As shown in the [tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells), you need to call the `iter_rows` method on an instance of a worksheet, for example (for [openpyxl 2.5.14](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5.14/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html) or earlier):

```
>>> for row in ws.iter_rows('A1:C2'):
...        for cell in row:
...            print cell
```

or

```
>>> for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=2):
...    for cell in row:
...        print(cell)
<Cell Sheet1.A1>
<Cell Sheet1.B1>
<Cell Sheet1.C1>
<Cell Sheet1.A2>
<Cell Sheet1.B2>
<Cell Sheet1.C2>
```

As your error message states, you are calling it on the `Worksheet` *type*, which won't work; it needs to be called on an *object*:

```
op.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows()  # wrong
```

See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13962583/699224) in another answer.

For older versions of openpyxl, you may need to ensure that you enable iterators when loading your workbook - see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/b_lab_TB_yM). This isn't required for more recent versions.

Here's a complete example which I just tested in the Python REPL (with openpyxl 1.8.3):

```
>>> import openpyxl as op
>>> wb = op.load_workbook('/tmp/test.xlsx', use_iterators=True)
>>> ws = wb.active
>>> for row in ws.iter_rows():
...   for cell in row:
...     print cell
... 
RawCell(row=1, column='A', coordinate='A1', internal_value=1.0, data_type='n', style_id='0', number_format='general')
RawCell(row=1, column='B', coordinate='B1', internal_value=10.0, data_type='n', style_id='0', number_format='general')
...
```

Comment: You don't need to enable iterators in recent versions; standard worksheets also have the `iter_rows()` method.

Comment: Thanks - I do seem to have a fairly old version (1.8.3; latest is 2.2.1) - will edit answer slightly.

Comment: Upgrading is generally well worth it. Will be pushing a 2.2.2 bug release soon but even so 2.2 is more reliable and faster than 1.8

Comment: For me, for row in ws.iter_rows('A1:C2'): did NOT work, but for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=2): did.  The 1st syntax gave a TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.