# Comparing items in an Excel file with Openpyxl in Python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I am working with a big set of data, which has 9 rows (B3:J3 in column 3) and stretches until B1325:J1325. Using Python and the Openpyxl library, I need to get the biggest and second biggest value of each row and print those to a new field in the same row. I already assigned values to single fields manually (headings), but cannot seem to even get the max value in my range automatically written to a new field. My code looks like the following:

```
for row in ws.rows['B3':'J3']:
sumup = 0.0
for cell in row:
    if cell.value != None:
    .........
```

It throws the error:

```
for row in ws.rows['B3':'J3']:
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How could I get to my goal here?

Comment: Try `ws['B3:J3']`…

Answer (score 0):

You can you `iter_rows` to do what you want.

Try this:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows('B3':'J3'):
    sumup = 0.0
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value != None:
        ........
```

Check out this answer for more info:
[How we can use iter_rows() in Python openpyxl package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792134/how-we-can-use-iter-rows-in-python-openpyxl-package)